# How to scrape url tags from JS code with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, url-parsing

I'm trying to scrape all URLs from within a JS script on a webpage using BeautifulSoup, the script looks like this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/XK38194y):

```
<script>(function(e,a){var t={"cdn_url":"https://f.vimeocdn.com","view":1,"request":{"files":{"dash":{"origin":"gcs","url":"https://skyfire.vimeocdn.com/1458528314-0x41f9db4bb4ec1a10ff0f95af0416acde0acbe440/143512140/video/431745862,431745863,431745861/master.json?base64_init=1","cdn":"fastly_skyfire","streams":[{"profile":112,"quality":"360p","id":431745862,"fps":25},{"profile":119,"quality":"1080p","id":431745863,"fps":25},{"profile":113,"quality":"720p","id":431745861,"fps":25}]},"hls":{"url":"https://skyfire.vimeocdn.com/1458528314-0x41f9db4bb4ec1a10ff0f95af0416acde0acbe440/143512140/video/431745862,431745863,431745861/master.m3u8","cdn":"fastly_skyfire"},"progressive":[{"profile":119,"width":1920,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":25,"url":"https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3702/5/143512140/431745863.mp4?token=56ef603a_0x9aadd2d9ee5d6efd3c0b34db826227d2d01423c6","cdn":"fastly","quality":"1080p","id":431745863,"origin":"gcs","height":1080},{"profile":112,"width":640,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":25,"url":"https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3702/5/143512140/431745862.mp4?token=56ef603a_0x828889dabd8ec15e0d2d4cb9c8e23809b7217052","cdn":"fastly","quality":"360p","id":431745862,"origin":"gcs","height":360},{"profile":113,"width":1280,"mime":"video/mp4","fps":25,"url":"https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3702/5/143512140/431745861.mp4?token=56ef603a_0xd248e4a1bd2a9700a92aacf727d5a3b68186a75f","cdn":"fastly","quality":"720p","id":431745861,"origin":"gcs","height":720}]},"ga_account":"UA-76641-35","expires":28792,"timestamp":1458499222,"signature":"7cef4747eae9195685e18285f78a7b1e","currency":"EUR","session":"c1f8c8ee9b746ae6b1ee6a454a2e311da606fa041458499222","cookie":{"scaling":1,"volume":1.0,"quality":"720p","hd":1,"captions":null},"cookie_domain":".vimeo.com","referrer":"http://racing4everyone.eu/2015/10/25/formula-e-201516formula-e-201516-round01-china-race/","comscore_id":"14640914","flags":{"dnt":0,"preload_video":"metadata_on_hover","plays":1,"webp":1,"flash_hls":1,"login":1,"partials":1,"blurr":0},"build":{"player":"67209230","js":"2.20.3"},"urls":{"zeroclip_swf":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/external/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf","js":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.20.3/js/player.js","proxy":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.20.3/proxy.html","flideo":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/flideo/1.0.3b10/flideo.swf","moog":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/moogaloop/6.3.4/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=143512140","comscore_js":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/external/streamsense.4.1408.29.min.js","blurr":"https://fresnel.vimeocdn.com/add/player-stats","chromeless_css":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.20.3/css/chromeless.css","vuid_js":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/js_opt/modules/utils/vuid.min.js","chromeless_js":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.20.3/js/chromeless.js","moog_js":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.20.3/js/moogaloop.js","zeroclip_js":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/external/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard-patch.js","css":"https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.20.3/css/player.css"},"country":"NL"},"player_url":"player.vimeo.com","video":{"allow_hd":1,"height":1080,"owner":{"account_type":"pro","name":"Mike Beging","img":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/bc83adfd0d41055c020aa37a5dba653b?d=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fportrait%2Fdefault-red_60x60.png&s=60","url":"https://vimeo.com/user48874148","img_2x":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/bc83adfd0d41055c020aa37a5dba653b?d=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fportrait%2Fdefault-red_120x120.png&s=120","id":48874148},"thumbs":{"1280":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/541116322_1280.jpg","960":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/541116322_960.jpg","640":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/541116322_640.jpg","base":"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/541116322"},"duration":7198,"id":143512140,"hd":1,"embed_code":"<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/143512140\" width=\"500\" height=\"281\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>","default_to_hd":1,"title":"FormulaE.2015-16.Round01.China","url":null,"privacy":"disable","share_url":"https://vimeo.com/143512140","width":1920,"embed_permission":"whitelist","fps":25.0},"build":{"player":"67209230","rpc":"dev"},"embed":{"autopause":1,"color":"00adef","on_site":0,"outro":"nothing","api":3,"player_id":"","quality":null,"settings":{"fullscreen":1,"byline":0,"like":0,"playbar":1,"title":0,"color":0,"branding":0,"share":0,"scaling":1,"logo":0,"collections":0,"info_on_pause":0,"watch_later":0,"portrait":0,"embed":0,"badge":0,"volume":1},"context":"embed.main","time":0,"loop":0,"autoplay":0},"vimeo_url":"vimeo.com","user":{"liked":0,"account_type":"none","progress":0,"owner":0,"watch_later":0,"logged_in":0,"id":0,"mod":0}};if(!t.request){return}if(typeof t.request==="object"&&"error"in t.request){if("html"in t.request){e.documentElement.innerHTML=t.request.html.replace(/&lt;/g,"<").replace(/&gt;/g,">")}return}var r=function(){try{return window.self!==window.top}catch(e){return true}}();if(!r&&/twitter/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&t.video.url){window.location=t.video.url}var n="exitFullscreen"in e||"webkitExitFullscreen"in e||"webkitCancelFullScreen"in e||"mozCancelFullScreen"in e||"msExitFullscreen"in e||"webkitEnterFullScreen"in e.createElement("video");var i=function(){var e=navigator;var a="Shockwave Flash";var t="application/x-shockwave-flash";var r="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash";if(typeof e.plugins!=="undefined"&&typeof e.plugins[a]==="object"){if(e.plugins[a].description&&!(typeof e.mimeTypes!=="undefined"&&e.mimeTypes[t]&&!e.mimeTypes[t].enabledPlugin)){return true}}try{if(window.ActiveXObject&&new ActiveXObject(r)){return true}}catch(n){}return false}();var o=function(){var a=e.createElement("video");return{h264:"canPlayType"in a&&a.canPlayType("video/mp4")!=="",textTracks:typeof TextTrackList!=="undefined"&&typeof a.textTracks!=="undefined"&&a.textTracks instanceof TextTrackList}}();var s=function(){var a=e.createElement("div");a.innerHTML="<svg/>";return(a.firstChild&&a.firstChild.namespaceURI)==="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"}();var l=/MSIE 9/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/Windows Phone/.test(navigator.userAgent);var c=/IE 10/.test(navigator.userAgent);window._gaq=[["player._setAccount",'UA-76641-35'],["player._setDomainName","player.vimeo.com"],["player._set","_anonymizeIp",true],["player._trackPageview"]];var u=n||c||l;var d=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];var m=e.createElement("script");var p=false;var f=false;if("text_tracks"in t.request&&(!o.textTracks||o.textTracks&&!o.h264)&&i){u=false}if(!s){u=false}var v="vod"in t.video&&t.video.vod.is_feature;if(v&&i&&("files"in t.request&&!t.request.files.dash)){u=false}if(u){a.className="player loading";var g=(new Date).getTime();m.src=t.request.urls.js;d.parentNode.insertBefore(m,d);m["onreadystatechange"in m?"onreadystatechange":"onload"]=function(){if(!p&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState==="loaded"||this.readyState==="complete")){p=true;var e=(new Date).getTime()-g;window._gaq.push(["player._trackTiming","Player","JavaScript Load",e]);f=new VimeoPlayer(a,t,y||{link:w,startTime:g})}};var y=false;var w=e.createElement("link");w.rel="stylesheet";w.href=t.request.urls.css+(typeof cacheBuster==="undefined"?"":cacheBuster);e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(w);w.onload=function(){y=true;var e=(new Date).getTime()-g;window._gaq.push(["player._trackTiming","Player","CSS Load",e])}}else if(i){a.innerHTML='<object id="flash-object" name="flash-object" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" data="'+t.request.urls.moog+"&z="+(new Date).getTime()+'"><param name="flashvars" value="clip_id='+t.video.id+"&amp;embed_location="+encodeURIComponent(t.request.referrer)+'&amp;js_getConfig=getConfig&amp;js_setConfig=setConfig&amp;js_onLoad=onMoogaloopLoaded&amp;api=1&amp;moogaloop_type=moogaloop"><param name="movie" value="'+t.request.urls.moog+"&z="+(new Date).getTime()+'"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="scalemode" value="noscale"></object>';var h=false;var T=e.getElementById("flash-object");window.onMoogaloopLoaded=function(){h=true;if(!f&&p){a.className="player";f=new VimeoPlayer(T,t)}};window.getConfig=function(){return t};window.setConfig=function(e){t=e};m.src=t.request.urls.moog_js;d.parentNode.insertBefore(m,d);m["onreadystatechange"in m?"onreadystatechange":"onload"]=function(){if(!p&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState==="loaded"||this.readyState==="complete")){p=true;if(!f&&h){f=new VimeoPlayer(T,t)}}}}else{a.innerHTML='<div class="fallback"><iframe src="/video/143512140/fallback?js&amp;referrer='+encodeURIComponent(t.request.referrer)+'" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>'}if(!t.request.flags.dnt){var _=e.createElement("script");_.async=true;_.src='https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';d.parentNode.insertBefore(_,d);window._vuid=[["pid",t.request.session]];var k=e.createElement("script");k.async=true;k.src=t.request.urls.vuid_js;d.parentNode.insertBefore(k,d)}})(document,document.getElementById("player"));</script>
```

I want to scrape all the video `"url"` links from within this JS script. I'm pretty convinced I can not do this with BeautifulSoup, so what could I use instead (and preferably, what is the correct code).

The URL also updates every time the page is loaded (and expires after a set time), so is it possible to write a bit of code that always gets a fresh URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to distinguish to videos from other links, but you could use the following function to scrape all URLs out of the document,

```
def all_links(content):
    links = []
    url_re = re.compile(r'"(https?://[^"]*)"')
    for m in url_re.finditer(content):
        links.append(m.group(1))
    return links
```

(That could be written as a one-line list comprehension, but it's a little more readable this way.)

To pull out a specific link based on its label in the JS objects, for example, the "cdn_url:" link, you could use a more specific regular expression, like this,

```
m = re.search(r'"cdn_url": *"(https?://[^"]*)"')
if m:
    link = m.group(1)
```

This should get you going.

Comment: It does not seem to work for the following [page](http://racing4everyone.eu/2015/10/25/formula-e-201516formula-e-201516-round01-china-race/). If I try to apply this code to the "inspect element" code I'm still unable to locate and print the url's that are within the relevant script. Also, the code I'm interested in is in the "inspect element" code, but not in the "source code", so how could I specifically search in the "inspect element" code?

Comment: It sounds like the page is downloading additional content after it has initially loaded.  If so, you won't be able to download and scrape the page using `requests` or `curl`, since they won't execute the javascript on the downloaded page.You might take a look at the [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) tool, which some of my co-workers use for front-end testing on pages like this.  I've never used it myself so I can't give you a simple script to execute, but you should be able to Google something up.

Comment: Precisely which link in the "inspect element" source is it that you're trying to extract?

Comment: I'm trying to extract: Within `<body>`, then `<script>`, then the `function(e,a)` and then the URLs that contain the `token`. You could also search for `.mp4` or `token` within the element code. Maybe I can track with which package this function is loaded and then try to get the code from that package?

Comment: I'll try again to get Selenium to work, seems like the only feasible option atm.

Comment: The link you're looking for is in the embedded vimeo player, which is loaded in an iframe.  I created a simple phantomjs script to load and dump the page, but that iframe isn't getting expanded; it may just be that phantom isn't waiting long enough for the response.  Good luck with Selenium.